# Development with docker - how to fetch data from a different localhost port

Tags: docker, localhost, port

My docker setup is very simple

```
version: '3.7'
services:

    php:
        build: ./docker/php
        ports: ['9000:9001']
        volumes:
            - ./symfony/:/var/www/symfony:cached

    nginx:
        build: docker/nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "7000:80"
        volumes:
            - ./docker/var/nginx:/var/log/nginx:cached
            - ./symfony/:/var/www/symfony:cached
```

So http://localhost:7000 is my route for development.
Here with php I try to fetch the api from another local docker installation with Port 8000 (or Port 80).

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8000');
$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost');
-> Warning: ... failed to open stream: Address not available
```

but a real url works fine

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://www.google.de')
```

I do not understand what's going on.
I would be very happy about any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for get the container ip:
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name

use this for get the host ip:
$(hostname -I| awk '{printf $1}')

$result = file_get_contents('http://host_ip:8000');

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can access the api via container IP with the browser, but not via php on localhost:7000. Here "Warning: file_get_contents(http://172.18.0.6:8000/api): failed to open stream: Operation timed out"

Comment: you could try with:  host_ip:8000/api

Comment: Thank you very much. I type "$(hostname -I| awk '{printf $1}')" in console, and can use this IP. I missed it ...